Where to find practice photos from Apollo training (ALSCC in particular)
We have lots of photos of the Apollo astronauts during their training sessions, and multiple sources mention practice photography, particularly panoramas (see Did Apollo-11 astronauts rehearse their photoshoots on Earth? and Were panoramic images taken during Apollo 15 planned and trained before on Earth?). The practice film magazines were developed overnight, and reviewed with the astronauts the next day.
Where would I find any archives of the practice photos they took? I’m particularly interested in finding stereo pairs taken in training with the Apollo Lunar Surface Closeup Camera (ALSCC). My search on images.nasa.gov comes up empty.
EDIT:
To be clear, I am not looking for pictures OF the astronauts in training. I’m looking for the pictures of rocks and soil that they took as practice during training, especially anything from the ALSCC. Maybe some ALSCC stereo pairs from Idaho, or a Hasselblad panorama from Arizona?

Try https://www.nasa.gov/history/alsj/a11/images11.html#Crew   https://www.nasa.gov/history/alsj/a12/images12.html#Crew   https://www.nasa.gov/history/alsj/a14/images14.html#Crew

Try also https://www.nasa.gov/history/alsj/a13/images13.html    https://www.nasa.gov/history/alsj/a15/images15.html#Crew

it is possible that some of the sources in comments and answers to When was stereoscopic photography first used intentionally on solar system body? might include some practice photos as well.
